# Next/previous featured image doesn't show, only current post image

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create a post navigation that shows featured images or show the images inside the content/youtube thumbnails when these are not available.

This is the code that I'm using for the thumbs inside the function.php file:

```
function vp_get_thumb_url($text, $size){

        global $post;
        $imageurl="";

// 1) FEATURED IMAGE
        // Check to see which image is set as "Featured Image"
        $featuredimg = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
        // Get source for featured image
        $img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($featuredimg, $size);
        // Set $imageurl to Featured Image
        $imageurl=$img_src[0];

// 2) 1ST ATTACHED IMAGE IMAGE
        // If there is no "Featured Image" set, move on and get the first image attached to the post
        if (!$imageurl) {
                // Extract the thumbnail from the first attached imaged
                $allimages =&get_children('post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&post_parent=' . $post->ID );

                foreach ($allimages as $img){
                        $img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($img->ID, $size);
                        break;
                }
                // Set $imageurl to first attached image
                $imageurl=$img_src[0];
        }

// 3) 1ST IMAGE URL IN POST
        // If there is no image attached to the post, look for anything that looks like an image and get that
        if (!$imageurl) {
                preg_match('/<\s*img [^\>]*src\s*=\s*[\""\']?([^\""\'>]*)/i' ,  $text, $matches);
                $imageurl=$matches[1];
        }

// 4) YOUTUBE SCREENSHOT
        // If there's no image attached or inserted in the post, look for a YouTube video
        if (!$imageurl){
                // look for traditional youtube.com url from address bar
                preg_match("/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+\.|)youtube\.com\/watch(\?v\=|\/v\/)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]{11})([^<\s]*)/", $text, $matches2);
                $youtubeurl = $matches2[0];
                $videokey = $matches2[3];
        if (!$youtubeurl) {
                // look for youtu.be 'embed' url
                preg_match("/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+\.|)youtu\.be\/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]{11})([^<\s]*)/", $text, $matches2);
                $youtubeurl = $matches2[0];
                $videokey = $matches2[2];
        }
        if ($youtubeurl)
            $videores = array ('maxresdefault','sddefault','mqdefault','hqdefault','default');
                for ($x = 0; $x < sizeof($videores); $x++) {
                    $imageurl = "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/{$videokey}/$videores[$x].jpg";
                    if (get_headers($imageurl)[0] == 'HTTP/1.0 200 OK') {
                        break;
                    }
                }
        }
        if (!$imageurl) {
        $imageurl = get_template_directory_uri() . '/placeholder.jpg';
        }

        // Spit out the image path
        return $imageurl;
}
```

And for the post navigation inside the entry-navigation.php file:

```
if ( is_singular( 'post' ) ) {
        
        $prev_post = get_previous_post();
        $next_post = get_next_post();

        $prev_thumb = '<a class="nav-thumb" href="' . get_permalink($prev_post->ID) . '"><div class="entry-thumbnail" style="background-image: url('. vp_get_thumb_url( $prev_post->post_content, array(150, 130) ) .')"></div></a>';
        $next_thumb = '<a class="nav-thumb" href="' . get_permalink($next_post->ID) . '"><div class="entry-thumbnail" style="background-image: url('. vp_get_thumb_url( $next_post->post_content, array(150, 130) ) .')"></div></a>';

        if ( empty( $prev_post ) && empty( $next_post ) ) {} else {
            
            echo '<div class="post-nav flex">';
            
            if ( get_adjacent_post( false, '', true ) ) {
                echo '<div class="prev-post flex">';
                echo $prev_thumb;
                echo '<div class="nav-text">';
                echo '<span class="label">Prev</span>';
                previous_post_link( '%link', '<div class="post-nav-title">%title</div>' );
                echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
            }

            if ( get_adjacent_post( false, '', false ) ) {
                echo '<div class="next-post flex">';
                echo $next_thumb;
                echo '<div class="nav-text">';
                echo '<span class="label">Next</span>';
                next_post_link( '%link', '<div class="post-nav-title">%title</div>' );
                echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
            }
            
            echo '</div>';
        }

}
```

It works properly for next/prev post images added inside the post, but not for posts with featured images. If I'm going to a post that has a featured image, it displays the image of the current post instead of the next/prev post (image attached). Any solution?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global **$post variable** is not being set correctly when retrieving the featured image.

Make vp_get_thumb_url() function to accept the $post object as a parameter instead of using a global variable.

```
function vp_get_thumb_url($post, $text, $size) {
    $imageurl = "";

    // 1) FEATURED IMAGE
    $featuredimg = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
    $img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($featuredimg, $size);
    $imageurl = $img_src[0];

    // Rest of the code...

    return $imageurl;
}
```

In your entry-navigation.php file, update the calls to vp_get_thumb_url() by passing the $post object as the first argument:

```
$prev_thumb = '<a class="nav-thumb" href="' . get_permalink($prev_post->ID) . '"><div class="entry-thumbnail" style="background-image: url('. vp_get_thumb_url($prev_post, $prev_post->post_content, array(150, 130)) .')"></div></a>';
$next_thumb = '<a class="nav-thumb" href="' . get_permalink($next_post->ID) . '"><div class="entry-thumbnail" style="background-image: url('. vp_get_thumb_url($next_post, $next_post->post_content, array(150, 130)) .')"></div></a>';
```

Comment: I added a new question concerning my widget which doesn't work well with the `vp_get_thumb_url()` function here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76417584/my-custom-wordpress-widget-doesnt-show-the-correct-post-image. Could you please help me with this? Thank you.