# My custom wordpress widget doesn't show the correct post image

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I'm trying to create a popular posts widget and use this code to show the thumbnail when there is no featured image available:

```php
function vp_get_thumb_url( $post, $text, $size ) {

    $imageurl = '';
    
    // 1) FEATURED IMAGE
    // Check to see which image is set as "Featured Image"
    $featuredimg = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
    
    // Get source for featured image
    $img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $featuredimg, $size );
    
    // Set $imageurl to Featured Image
    $imageurl = $img_src[0];
    
    // 2) 1ST ATTACHED IMAGE IMAGE
    // If there is no "Featured Image" set, move on and get the first image attached to the post
    if ( ! $imageurl ) {
        // Extract the thumbnail from the first attached imaged
        $allimages =&get_children( 'post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&post_parent=' . $post->ID );

        foreach ( $allimages as $img ) {
            $img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $img->ID, $size );
            break;
        }
        
        // Set $imageurl to first attached image
        $imageurl = $img_src[0];
    }
    
    // 3) 1ST IMAGE URL IN POST
    // If there is no image attached to the post, look for anything that looks like an image and get that
    if ( ! $imageurl ) {
        preg_match( '/<\s*img [^\>]*src\s*=\s*[\""\']?([^\""\'>]*)/i', $text, $matches );
        $imageurl = $matches[1];
    }
    
    // 4) YOUTUBE SCREENSHOT
    // If there's no image attached or inserted in the post, look for a YouTube video
    if ( ! $imageurl ) {
        // look for traditional youtube.com url from address bar
        preg_match( "/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+\.|)youtube\.com\/watch(\?v\=|\/v\/)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]{11})([^<\s]*)/", $text, $matches2 );
        $youtubeurl = $matches2[0];
        $videokey = $matches2[3];
        
        if ( ! $youtubeurl ) {
            // look for youtu.be 'embed' url
            preg_match( "/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+\.|)youtu\.be\/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]{11})([^<\s]*)/", $text, $matches2 );
            $youtubeurl = $matches2[0];
            $videokey = $matches2[2];
        }
        
        if ( $youtubeurl ) {
            $videores = array( 'maxresdefault', 'sddefault', 'mqdefault', 'hqdefault', 'default' );
        }
        
        for ( $x = 0; $x < sizeof( $videores ); $x++ ) {
            $imageurl = "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/{$videokey}/$videores[$x].jpg";
            
            if ( get_headers( $imageurl )[0] == 'HTTP/1.0 200 OK' ) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    if ( ! $imageurl ) {
        $imageurl = get_template_directory_uri() . '/placeholder.jpg';
    }

    // Spit out the image path
    return $imageurl;
}
```

The widget's code:

```php
class my_widget extends WP_Widget {

    public function __construct() {
        $widget_ops = array(
            'classname'                   => 'mywidget-popular',
            'description'                 => __( 'Your site\'s most popular Posts.' ),
            'customize_selective_refresh' => true,
            'show_instance_in_rest'       => true,
        );
        parent::__construct( 'mywidget-popular', __( 'Popular Posts' ), $widget_ops );
        $this->alt_option_name = 'mywidget-popular';
    }
    
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        if ( ! isset( $args['widget_id'] ) ) {
            $args['widget_id'] = $this->id;
        }
    
        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );
        $number = apply_filters('widget_number', $instance['number']);
        // Post settings
        $thumb = $instance[ 'thumb' ] ? 'true' : 'false';
    
        echo $args['before_widget'];
    
        if ( ! empty( $title ) )
            echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];
        ?>
    
        <ul>
            <?php
            $top_posts = new WP_Query( array(
                'posts_per_page' => $number,
                'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
                'order' => 'DESC'
            ) );
            if ( $top_posts->have_posts() ) : 
                while ( $top_posts->have_posts() ) : 
                    $top_posts->the_post();
                    ?>
    
                    <li>
                        <?php if( 'on' == $instance[ 'thumb' ] ) : ?>
                            <div class="popular-thumb">
                                <a href="<?php esc_url(the_permalink()); ?>">
                                    <div style="background-image: url(<?php echo vp_get_thumb_url($post, $post->post_content, 'full'); ?>)"></div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <h6><a href="<?php esc_url(the_permalink()); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h6>
                    </li>
                    <?php
                endwhile; 
            endif;
            wp_reset_postdata();
            ?>
        </ul>
        <?php
        echo $args['after_widget'];
    }
    
    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        return $new_instance;
    }
    
    public function form( $instance ) {
        $defaults = array( 'title' => __( 'Popular Posts' ), 'number' => 3, 'thumb' => true );
        $instance = wp_parse_args( ( array ) $instance, $defaults );
    
        include( plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '/views/form.php' );
    }
}

// Register and load the widget
function mywidget_load_widget() {
    register_widget( 'my_widget' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'mywidget_load_widget' );
```

It shows the image when there is a featured image available but the problem is that when there is no featured image but the post have an image in the content, it shows the featured image from my previous post. Any idea why it's not working?

PS. It seems that adding `global $post` before `$top_posts = new WP_Query` solves the issue but I'm looking for a different solution. Help?

Comment: There are a couple things wrong with the code: (1) parameters to `vp_get_thumb_url()` are incorrect (first parameter should be a string, `WP_Post` object provided), and (2) `the_permalink()` does not return a value, so it can't be escaped. Try fixing those, and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Hi Caleb, the permalink is working but I'm not sure what I need to add as the first parameter for the `vp_get_thumb_url()`. Could you please provide an example? Also the widget settings on the backend disappear when it loads the preview and I want to show only the settings. How can I do that? Thank you.

Comment: I created another post and I was wrong about displaying the image from my post navigation... it actually displays the featured image from my last post (even if I delete it). But if I'm adding a featured image to the post, it displays the correct one. This is strange.

Comment: @Caleb I added `global $post;` after `WP_Query` and it fixed the issue. But is this the solution or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Look at the function definition, and compare it with the function call: the first parameter of the function should be a string, but it's not. I recommend not adding `global $post` until the things I mentioned are fixed.

Comment: Oh, now I see why you're saying that the first parameter is not correct. I forgot to add the edited function which is `function vp_get_thumb_url($post, $text, $size)` without the global $post. The problem is that it is not working inside my widget's code without global $post before WP_Query. Sorry for the confusion!